# K8s DaemonSet stills restart

Tags: kubernetes

Im starting with K8s and I have problem with my DaemonSet resource. When I apply it, it goes to `Running` state, then `Completed` and then `CrashLoopBackOff` and then again to running etc. I would like to have all my pods to be in `Running` state. Here is my manifest:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: ds-test
  labels:
    app: busybox-ds
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: busybox-ds
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 0
      maxSurge: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: busybox-ds
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: busybox-ds
        image: busybox
```

Could somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `busybox` image just runs `sh` as its command. If it's not being interacted with, it immediately exits, and hence why you see your pod go to the `Completed` state.

You need to have that image run a command that will keep its process running.

Using `tail -f /dev/null` is a common way to do this. So your manifest would look like:

```yaml
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: busybox-ds
        image: busybox
        command:
        - tail
        - -f
        - /dev/null
```